# Regex - identifying a unique digit to stop the match

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to split a body of text based on identifying section numbers within the text. I am using it to identify the start of the section number and capture all the following text in the match until the next section number. An example of what the body of text might look like is, where Â§ 1.XX-X identifies the section:

```
Â§ 1.11-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.15-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-2 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-3 text
text
text
```

The pattern I am currently using is `(^Â§\s1\.\d{1,4}.+?)(?=^Â§\s1\.\d{1,4})` which creates a match for each section. However, I would like new matches only when the numbers immediately following the period are unique. So in this example these numbers are 11, 15, and 21; so I would want my matches to be:

```
Match 1:
Â§ 1.11-1 text
text
text
Match 2:
Â§ 1.15-1 text
text
text
Match 3:
Â§ 1.21-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-2 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-3 text
text
text
```

Comment: This: [`(?:^Â§\s1\.(\d{1,4})(?!\d).+?)(?=^Â§\s1\.(?!\1\D)\d{1,4}|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/JUAedI/2)?

Comment: @ markalex Thank you, that was what I needed.
I also realized there will be some section numbers with a single capital letter at the end. In that case, I need it to be identified as its own match (e.g. everything using 199 is one match but then everything using 199A is a separate match.
I've attempted to update but something is off: https://regex101.com/r/qMDKa0/1

Answer (score 0):

Without having a dot match a newline, you can use a capture group `(Â§\s1\.\d{1,4})\b` to match for example a part like `Â§ 1.21`.

Then match all lines that do not start with this pattern `Â§\s1\.\d{1,4}\b`

After the match, optionally repeat all lines that start with the value in capture group 1 using a backreference `\1` and the same matching logic again.

```
^(Â§\s1\.\d{1,4})\b.*(?:\n(?!Â§\s1\.\d{1,4}\b).*)*(?:\n\1.*(?:\n(?!Â§\s1\.\d{1,4}\b).*)*)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yePeHn/1) (note that is has the multiline flag enabled)

Answer (score 0):

This regex doesn't work on regex101 but works on Notepad++ and with python.

### regex:

```
Â§ (\d\.\d+)-\d+ (.*\r?\n)*?(?=Â§ |$)(?!Â§ \1)
```

### tricky parts:

1. capture group we want to compare later using \1:

```
(\d\.\d+)
```

2. matching the lines but non-greedy:

```
(.*\r?\n)*?
```

3. lookahead to see a line matching "Â§ ":

```
(?=Â§ |$)
```

but not matching "Â§ " followed by the same number than the first capture group:

```
(?!Â§ \1)
```

4. the "|$" is used for the last match which doesn't have a "Â§ " the next line.

### python code:

```py
import re


str = """Â§ 1.11-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.15-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-1 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-2 text
text
text
Â§ 1.21-3 text
text
text
"""

matches = re.finditer(r'Â§ (\d\.\d+)-\d+ (.*\r?\n)*?(?=Â§ |$)(?!Â§ \1)', str)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group(0))
```